# unit testing to validate a password

Tags: c#, unit-testing, validation, passwords

Can someone provide some sample code for a unit test that validates a users password?

```
            //set test to crate user 
            AsaMembershipProvider prov = this.GetMembershipProvider();
            //call get user
            MembershipCreateStatus status;
            MembershipUser user = prov.CreateUser("testUserX", "12345", "test.UserX@abc.com", "", "", true, null, out status);
            user = prov.GetUser("testUserX", false);



            //TODO Asserts
            Assert.AreEqual(status, MembershipCreateStatus.Success);
            Assert.AreEqual(user.UserName, "testUserX");
            Assert.AreEqual(user.Email, "test.userx@abc.com");
            //Assert.AreEqual(password, "12345");
```

Comment: Edit your question with the contents of your comment, it'll help readability. Secondly, you should be able to pull the password hash from somewhere. Just test to ensure the hash of "12345" and the hash from the database match.

Comment: Can you post rest of your test code?

Comment: Shouldn't asserting status == success be enough? Why do you need to validate the password (and username for that matter) in your unit test for the membership provider?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to assert that the password is correct, instead assert that you are able to authenticate, rather than testing the password directly.  Testing the provider's functionality is a bit redundant.

```
 Assert.AreEqual(status, MembershipCreateStatus.Success);

 var isAuthenticated = Membership.ValidateUser(user.Username, "12345");

 Assert.IsTrue(isAuthenticated);
 Assert.AreEqual(user.UserName, "testUserX");
 Assert.AreEqual(user.Email, "test.userx@abc.com");
```